# How to call servlet doPost() method from browser

Tags: java

I'm new to servlet programming and I have written a simple servlet running on Apache Tomcat 9.0.39. The logic in the `doPost()` and the `doGet()` methods are different from each other. I can simply invoke the `doGet()` as follow and receive an accurate response from the servlet:

```
localhost:8080/myservlet/load?id="4"
```

The `doPost()` method is sending two parameters "author" and "title" to the servlet to store. Ultimately, I'd like to keep this simple and not to develop an Html form to submit the values for the `"author"` and the `"title"` to the servlet. Is there a way I can invoke the `doPost()` from the browser as I had for the `doGet()` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a developer http client like Postman.

Comment: @ernest_k that's not the browser

Comment: Thanks, I have already looked into JS Html forms, CRUL and I will look into Postman as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - the OP explicitly said they didn't want to develop and html page just to test this in a browser.

Comment: Well, if you want to test something different than HTTP GET in a browser but don't want to create HTML/JS code, then it's impossible.

Comment: Luiggi, I wanted to see if calling the doPost() from the browser was feasible but it seems that I have to choose between Html form, JavaScript, Postman, CRUL, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it does not matter if it is servlet or not. The problem area is regarding Http protocol.
From your browser you can send post request, of course.

1. In you browser, you should have HTML FORM and make the form's method attribute "post" and set the action attribute as url for which you want to post.
2. Or you could use Javascript fetch api to send post message as ajax.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch